# JQuery: Show/Hide Div buttons works on single but not on select all deselect

Tags: jquery

I am having issues with a script I am making whereby I have a list of items in a table which after searching I may want to modify these by selecting them. These options are in a Div with the ID "ProjectListButton". The script works everywhere except when I deselect "selectall".

So when I click the radio id select all, it selects all and shows the div. When I deselect the radio select all it does not remove the Div.

```
<div id="ProjectListButton" style="display:none;">With selected: </div>
<div id="data-table">
<table cellspacing='0'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input class="pChk" id="selectall" type="checkbox"></th>
            <th>Keyword</th>
            <th>Searches (daily)</th>
            <th>SEO Traffic (daily)</th>
            <th>Competitiveness</th>
            <th>SEO Value</th>
            <th>Average CPC</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="pChk" type="checkbox" name="keywords" value="example"></td>
            <td>example/td>
            <td>1,332</td>
            <td>559</td>
            <td><div style="height:15px; border:1px solid #800000; width:100%"><div style="height:15px;background:#990000; width:1.05%;"></div></td>
            <td><div style="height:15px; border:1px solid #2E8AE6; width:100%"><div style="height:15px;background:#3399FF; width:3.83%;"></div></td>
            <td>$15.86</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</section>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("search").submit();
    }
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#selectall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
                if(this.checked) { // check select status
                    $('.pChk').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                        this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "pChk"               
                    });
                }else{
                    $('.pChk').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                        $(this).prop("checked",false); //deselect all checkboxes with class "pChk"                       
                    });         
                }
            });

        });
        $('.pChk').click(function() {
            if ( $('.pChk:checked').length > 0) {
                $("#ProjectListButton").show();
            } else {
                $("#ProjectListButton").hide();
            }
        }); 

    </script>
```

I have been pulling my hair out as to why. One thing to note is that the select all radio has both the pChk class and the selectall id, could this be causing an issue?

edit: i have added the html as well.  Vanojx1 that solution did not work

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: try to change this.checked = false; with $(this).prop("checked",false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your jquery code, in your jquery code i have found that  `$('.pChk').click(function() {` this code is not in `$(document).ready(function() {`. so please put that code in to `$(document).ready(function() {`

For I.E.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selectall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
            if(this.checked) { // check select status
                $('.pChk').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "pChk"               
                });
            }else{
                $('.pChk').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "pChk"                       
                });         
            }
        });
        $('.pChk').click(function() {
          if ( $('.pChk:checked').length > 0) {
            $("#ProjectListButton").show();
          } else {
            $("#ProjectListButton").hide();
          }
        }); 
    });


</script>
```

Comment: That was it. Always something simple!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  var checkbox = $('.checkbox');
  
  $('#selectall').on('change', function(event) { 
    checkbox.prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="selectall">
  Select All
</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
</body>
</html>
```